# Why is this code on vectors giving runtime error?

Tags: c++, vector

What is wrong with this code , why is it giving runtime error ?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {

        vector < int > a[2];
        a[0][0]=1;
        a[1][0]=2;
        cout << a[0][0];
        cout << a[1][0];
        return 0;
    }
```

Also please correct it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why is it giving runtime error ?

Because the two vectors are empty, so you can't access their elements using `[]`.

> Also please correct it .

```
    vector < int > a[2];
    a[0].push_back(1);
    a[1].push_back(2);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , Also what is the difference between vector < int > a[2] and vector < int > a(2) ?

Comment: @AnmolSood: The first is an array of two empty vectors; the second is a single vector initialised with a size of two.

Answer (score 3):

Because a is an array of two empty vectors. You are trying to access elements that don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

> why is it giving runtime error ?

```
vector < int > a[2];
```

After this declaration vectors are empty yet. So this is undefined behavior trying to acces their elements. This is the cause of runtime error. You need to initialize them first:

```
vector < int > a[2];
a[0].push_back(1);
a[1].push_back(2);
```

Declaration

```
std::vector<int>(10);
```

specify that this vector has size of 10.
If you want to specify the size of `vector` in container you can do it:

```
std::vector<int> va[2];
va[0] = std::vector<int>(10);
```

However this might be better:

```
va[0].reserve(100);  // but this just pre-allocates memory, doesn't initialize
```

Comment: In your last line, you probably mean `va[0].resize(100)`, which has the same behavior as `va[0] = std::vector<int>(10)`

Comment: Indeed, `reserve` doesn't increase the size, it just pre-allocates memory. It will probably mask the error, replacing a friendly protection fault with more subtle undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

`operator[]` provides no bounds checking. If you used `at` instead, you would get a nice exception telling you what the problem is. It is undefined behavior to provide an index `n` if the container size is **not** greater than `n`.

```
a[0].at(0) =1;
a[1].at(0) =2;
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'

  what():  vector::_M_range_check
```